# Why is this function firing three times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code snippet to track the clicks of an add to cart button three times.

It's inside a pop up 'quick view' modal if you are confused why I've written it this way.

To be precise - this part is firing three times on every click:

```
$(".qlBtns").one("click", function() {

  mboxDefine('dynamicElement5', 'QuickViewAddToCartClicked');
  mboxUpdate('QuickViewAddToCartClicked', 'Clicked=Yess');

});
```

Complete snippet below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quickview_btn").click(function() {

    var quickview_url = $(this).attr("href");
    var qvURL = $(this).attr("href");

    $(".quickview_btn").colorbox({
      href: qvURL,
      opacity: 0.6,
      onComplete: function() {

        $(".qlBtns").one("click", function() {
          mboxDefine('dynamicElement5', 'QuickViewAddToCartClicked');
          mboxUpdate('QuickViewAddToCartClicked', 'Clicked=Yess');
        });

      }
    });

    mboxDefine('dynamicElement', 'QuickViewPLPclicked');
    mboxUpdate('QuickViewPLPclicked', 'paramURL=' + quickview_url);
  });
});
```

Comment: How many `$(".quickview_btn")` you have ? Three?

Comment: How many times the `onComplete` event will be called?

Comment: I would recommend using event delegation (if the `(".qlBtns")` element does not exist before the colorbox will be attached) the bind your click-event handler. It is never a good idea to bind an event-handler inside another event-handler.

Answer (score 1):

you should bind the event

`$(".qlBtns").on("click", function() {});`

only once to get it triggered a single time, since you are binding the event inside the another **function** **oncomplete** callback , it is possible that the **event is getting binded more than once**. You should do this binding outside the .**colorbox** function. in case you can not do this i will suggest you to unbind and bind the event by using below code.

```
$(".qlBtns").off("click").on("click", function() {});
```